# is there a simple way to convert a conan package to rpm

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, conan

We are using conan to handle dependencies between different teams during the development phase of our project.

In the end, when all software parts are ok, they will be deployed on a centos environement image that is deployed in our customers factories.

Conan makes the developement phase easier (in some way) but make installation on the target env (centos) painful as all packages are spread accross .conan directories and need virtual_runenv.sh to be sourced etc... (also makes it *really* painful to share /etc config files between projects)

I was trying to invoke conan for rpmbuild writing

```
%build
conan install .
conan build .
cmake -DCMAKE_INTALL_PREFIX=/usr .
make

%install
make PREFIX=/usr DESTDIR=%{?buildroot} install
```

This looks so weird to me as I need to duplicate more or less the conan_file.py and need to rewrite all dependencies manually in the .spec file.

Would it be some way to create rpm packages from the conan stuff? (so that binaries are just installed "normally" in the end?)

Comment: Have you checked the [`cpack-generators`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cpack-generators.7.html), introduced in CMake 3.13? If you're already using CMake in your team, perhaps you can/should use CPack to do the RPM generation for you?

Comment: yes cpack works great, but still needs to have the cpack script to be written thus duplicates somehow the conan_file.py, that's why I would expect conan to allow such conversion.

Comment: You can add cpack as commented. Use `self.run("cpack -G RPM %s" % self.build_folder)` command after install. For example: https://github.com/uilianries/cpack-example/blob/40fc728b621bce8e2f18a7911a0b31dcd3883cdb/conanfile.py#L20